# Error when running tests: Unable to locate NamespaceHandler for namespace [http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth2]

Tags: maven, mule

When I run the app (with Maven support), it works fine, but when I run `mvn test` (functional test) it gives me the error: `Unable to locate NamespaceHandler for namespace [http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/oauth2]`

It looks like it comes from this:

`<http:request-config name="ApiRest" protocol="HTTPS"   doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" basePath="rest" host="${api.endpointUrl}" port="443">
    <oauth2:client-credentials-grant-type clientId="${api.client_id}" clientSecret="${api.client_secret}">
        <oauth2:token-request tokenUrl="${api.endpointUrl}/oauth/token" />
    </oauth2:client-credentials-grant-type>
</http:request-config>`

What exactly is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue before but it is complaining about `spring-ss` namespace. See if the same solution will work with you.

Add these jars on your pom.xml which may be responsible for that namespace.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-module-boot-ee</artifactId>
    <version>${mule.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-module-ws</artifactId>
    <version>${mule.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Maybe worth trying with `mule-module-oauth` module as well.

Good luck!

Comment: You are correct the maven dependency containing that namespace is:
<groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
<artifactId>mule-module-oauth</artifactId>

Comment: `mule-module-oauth` did it. Thank you all